# How to check a file is properly zipped in HDFS or not?

Tags: hadoop, zip, hdfs

How to check a file is properly zipped in HDFS or not?

I can use the below command in normal unix file system

```html
zip -T filename.zip
```

But when trying the similar command in HDFS, I am getting error.

```html
hadoop fs -zip -T filename.zip
```

I am getting the below error for the above command

```html
-zip: Unknown command
```

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop allows only `limited commands` to be executed. You `cannot use zip command` in HDFS shell.

Available commands are:

`appendToFile`, `cat`, `chgrp`, `chmod`, `chown`, `copyFromLocal`, `copyToLocal`, `count`, `cp`, `du`, `dus`, `expunge`, `get`, `getfacl`, `getfattr`, `getmerge`, `ls`, `lsr`, `mkdir`, `moveFromLocal`, `moveToLocal`, `mv`, `put`, `rm`, `rmr`, `setfacl`, `setfattr`, `setrep`, `stat`, `tail`, `test`, `text`, `touchz`

Refer [Apache Hadoop File System Shell Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html), for list of allowed commands with examples that can be used in HDFS shell.

Comment: Could you please let me know what can be the alternative way to check the zip file validity in HDFS. Whether it could have been done through hadoop streaming command or not.